# Angular Ivy, how a text node points to its ng-template

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ivy

I need to find in tests that a text node of `tpl1` belongs to a `ng-template` after its render.

```html
1
<ng-template tpl>
  tpl1
</ng-template>
2
```

if to find the debugNode of `tpl1` after its render, then its parent points to the `component`'s node, but **I want to ensure that the debugNode of `tpl1` derives from `ng-template`**.

So far, I was **able** to do that in **classic** mode, but **cannot** find a way to do that in **ivy**.

- a link to stackblitz in classic (works): https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5wg14l-b39rck?file=src%2Ftest.spec.ts

There is a min example below, any solution (not only with elDef and tNode) would work for me.

```js
import {Component, DebugNode, Directive, TemplateRef, VERSION, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";

@Directive({
  selector: '[tpl]',
})
class TplDirective {
  public constructor(public readonly tpl: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'target',
  template: `
    1
    <ng-template tpl>
      tpl1
    </ng-template>
    2
  `,
})
class TargetComponent {
  @ViewChild(TplDirective, {
    read: TemplateRef,
  }) public readonly tpl?: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild(TplDirective, {
    read: ViewContainerRef,
  }) public readonly vcr?: ViewContainerRef;
}

describe('issue-289', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [TplDirective, TargetComponent],
  }).compileComponents());

  fit('finds right parent in ivy', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TargetComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const componentEl = fixture.debugElement;
    const component: TargetComponent = componentEl.componentInstance;

    // check that only defaults have been rendered
    expect (componentEl.childNodes.length).toEqual(3);
    const [txtEl1, tplEl, txtEl2] = componentEl.childNodes;
    expect(txtEl1.nativeNode.nodeName).toEqual('#text');
    expect(tplEl.nativeNode.nodeName).toEqual('#comment');
    expect(txtEl2.nativeNode.nodeName).toEqual('#text');

    // rendering the template
    component.vcr.createEmbeddedView(component.tpl);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // looking for the new element
    expect (componentEl.childNodes.length).toEqual(4);
    const txtTplEl = componentEl.childNodes.find(el => el !== txtEl1 && el !== tplEl && el !== txtEl2);
    expect(txtTplEl.nativeNode.nodeName).toEqual('#text');

    // getting internal node, 1st is classic, 2nd is ivy
    const tplElNode = (tplEl.injector as any).elDef || (tplEl.injector as any)._tNode;
    expect(tplElNode).toBeDefined();

    // FIXME find how txtTplEl points to tplEl
    // in classic (not ivy) it works like that
    const txtTplNode = (txtTplEl as any)._debugContext?.view?.parentNodeDef;

    // should succeed
    expect(txtTplNode).toEqual(tplElNode);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about  checking it like this

```
const view = component.vcr.createEmbeddedView(component.tpl);
       /\
       ||
   assign to variable

expect(view.rootNodes.includes(txtTplEl.nativeNode)).toBeTruthy();
```

It doesn't touch private API and should work in both versions.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5wg14l-jjnfn1?file=src%2Ftest.spec.ts)**

Comment: Yep, that's where I landed for now, with extracting `vcr`, then `vr` and then its `rootNodes`, but currently I discovered an issue, with a nested template `<ng-template tpl>tpl1<ng-template tpl>tpl2</ng-template></ng-template>` the first `vr.rootNodes` has both of them, apart from that, any call of `injector.get(VCR)` creates a `#comment` node instead of throwing an error, if it hasn't been created before (on a div for example). https://github.com/satanTime/ng-mocks/blob/issues/289/libs/ng-mocks/src/lib/mock-helper/crawl/el-def-get-parent.ts#L23-L37. But so far, it is the best one.

Comment: Can you please recreate the case with nested templates?